# Automatically add first day of the month

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I have an input which recieve only month/Year values and need to store this values in a MySQL format (Y-m-d).

```
'vencimento' => Carbon::createFromFormat( 'm/Y', request('vencimento') )->toDateString(),
```

But it is adding 30 as default day. How can set 1 as default day?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest

```
$date = Carbon::createFromFormat( 'm/Y', request('vencimento') 
$date->day = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse like this `Carbon::create(2012, 1, 31, 0);`

http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-addsub